# Join versus SecondaryTable

Tags: openjpa

Trying to understand the pros & cons of SecondaryTables here.

I have 2 tables with schema like this:

**Table1**          pk ID int, NAME varchar(100),  DESC varchar(256)
**Table1_Strings**  fk Table1_ID int, LONG_STRING text

Each Table1 entry will have 0-1 Table1_Strings entry.  I'd like to lazy load the Table1_Strings.

What is the difference if I treat Table1_Strings as a SecondaryTable or with a Join??  Clearly I don't really understand the difference.  This is my first taste of OpenJPA.

thanks!  Sorry for the ugly formatting above!